# Varchar(40) is not storing more characters

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have a database column with varchar(40) ... if i try to store a string greater than 40 characters then it is storing only the first 40 charactes.
Its a laravel 5.0 project and i am using Eloquent for interacting with mysql.

Why is it not storing more characters than 40? Fixture?

Is there a way that allowed limit auto-increases if input size exceeds 40 ?

Comment: It is clear because of `varchar(40)`, alter this column to store more chars in it `varchar(120)` for example

Comment: what does 40 means in 'varchar(40)'?Do you know that?

Comment: use varchar not more than 255, becouse it's maximal value for indexing.
If more than 255 - use text.

in you case - varchar (max length here)

Comment: ok ... is there a way that size autoincreases if string length exceeds 40 ?

Comment: This is like asking how to store a picture in a DATETIME column... Why do you restrict content to 40 chars if that's not what you want?

Comment: i restricted it to 40 because there are many columns .. like 90 columns in single table... i think i better normalise my database

Comment: post comment as answer.. i will accept it as answer. thank you for your replies

Comment: Of course, make the column length as length as you need but not more than 255.
MySQL will assign size as your input length but not more than the length you specify in definition of the column

Comment: weejah.. please post comment as answer , i will choose it to be the the final answer. thanks... this was a really silly question i kno :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear because of `varchar(40)`, alter this column to store more chars in it `varchar(120)` for example.
MySQL will assign size as your input length but not more than the length you specify in definition of the column